# How getc is defined?

Tags: c

I've heard that `getc`, unlike `fgetc`, is a macro and wanted to check this. Where can I find the source code for `getc`?

Comment: choose one landuage

Comment: If it doesn't begin with #define then it's probably not a macro. Can you post the code you're looking at and tell us which library it's from? Different systems and compilers will use different implementations.

Comment: sorry im talking about C

Comment: `between fgetc and getc is that the first one a function and the second one is a macro` No, `getc` _may be_ a macro.

Comment: "We know that the difference between fgetc and getc is that the first one a function and the second one is a macro". No we don't know that. There is no requirement for `getc` to be a macro. If you are referring to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getc) it says: **may be** implemented as a macro

Comment: @JohnFilleau Maybe because English is not my first language I don't understand your point. I was trying to say that `getc` may or may not be a macro and thus the implementation that the OP is looking at may not have `#define` if it is the latter.

Comment: @kaylum my apologies - I was just making a joke (not against you). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user3386109 you mean it's better to implement getc as a macro ?

Comment: @JohnFilleau It's not from a code, i just read it on many websites and books.

Comment: Even if it is implemented as a macro, it **must** be implemented as a library function. You can call the library function with `(getc)(stdin)` (the parenthesis around the identifier stop the preprocessor from expanding the (possible) macro).

Answer (score 4):

I believe the part [from C99 standard about `getc()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.7.5p2) says it all:

> The getc function is equivalent to fgetc, except that if it is implemented as a macro, it may evaluate stream more than once, so the argument should never be an expression with side effects.

So doing:

```
// a function that does some side effects
// and also returns a FILE*
FILE *func_that_returns_file();

int main() {
   getc(func_that_returns_file())
}
```

is dissallowed, because it *may* call the function multiple times.

Comment: It's not disallowed unless it has side effects. Of course, if it's really slow you might want to rethink your approach, but it's legal.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in comments, `getc` can be but is not required to be implemented as a macro.  On the contrary, it *must* have a function implementation.  None of this is specific to `getc`.  From the C99 specification, section 7.1.4/1:

> Any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a function-like macro defined in the header, so if a library function is declared explicitly when its header is included, one of the techniques shown below can be used to ensure the declaration is not affected by such a macro. Any macro definition of a function can be suppressed locally by enclosing the name of the function in parentheses, because the name is then not followed by the left
>   parenthesis that indicates expansion of a macro function name. For the same syntactic reason, it is permitted to take the address of a library function even if it is also defined as a macro.

So, in fact, while a C implementation might choose to implement some library functions as macros, it must *also* provide non-macro implementations so that they may be used as function pointers (e.g. if you were to pass `getc` as an argument to another function).

Answer (score 3):

> We know that the difference between fgetc and getc is that the first one a function and the second one is a macro…

We do not know this, because it is not true. The C implementation **must** define each function specified in the C standard library as an actual function.<sup>1</sup> The C implementation **may** **also** define any function as a function-like macro. Even if the implementation provides a macro for any standard library function, it must also provide an actual function.

Thus, a function declaration of `getc` appears in `stdio.h` (directly in it or indirectly, in some file it includes). `stdio.h` may also contain a definition of `getc` using `#define`.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> This applies to those functions the implementation is required to provide; some headers or functions are optional in various circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

from: `https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/libio/getc.c.html`

The source code for `getc()` is:

```
/* Copyright (C) 1993-2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.
   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.
   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
   As a special exception, if you link the code in this file with
   files compiled with a GNU compiler to produce an executable,
   that does not cause the resulting executable to be covered by
   the GNU Lesser General Public License.  This exception does not
   however invalidate any other reasons why the executable file
   might be covered by the GNU Lesser General Public License.
   This exception applies to code released by its copyright holders
   in files containing the exception.  */
#include "libioP.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#undef _IO_getc
int
_IO_getc (FILE *fp)
{
  int result;
  CHECK_FILE (fp, EOF);
  if (!_IO_need_lock (fp))
    return _IO_getc_unlocked (fp);
  _IO_acquire_lock (fp);
  result = _IO_getc_unlocked (fp);
  _IO_release_lock (fp);
  return result;
}
#undef getc
weak_alias (_IO_getc, getc)
weak_alias (_IO_getc, fgetc)
#ifndef _IO_MTSAFE_IO
#undef getc_unlocked
weak_alias (_IO_getc, getc_unlocked)
weak_alias (_IO_getc, fgetc_unlocked)
#endif
```